# Excel IF function with Datedif function nested is not working

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an excel spreadsheet and I am trying to make a column that calculates the difference of days between 2 dates. If the difference is less than or equal to 45 days the 0.5 is added to that column. If it is greater than 45 days then nothing is added. I cannot figure out why it won't accept my function I have made

```
=IF(DATEDIF 'Jira Sheet'!$I2,'Jira Sheet'!$J2,"D") < =45, + 0.5,+  0)
```

Comment: Missing the opening `(` before DATEDIF: `=IF(DATEDIF('Jira Sheet'!$I2,'Jira Sheet'!$J2,"D") <=45,  0.5,  0)`   Also remove the space in `< =`

Comment: So what if everytime there is a date range in the different rows it adds 0.5 points if the start and end date are <= 45 days?

Comment: I'm not following your question - your formula only looks at row2.

Comment: Right, that was because if I put say =IF(DATEDIF('Jira Sheet'!$I:I,'Jira Sheet'!$J:J,"D") <=45, 0.5, 0) it is not counting the other rows that have date ranges in them it is only adding 0.5 for one row when I place a whole column into the function (I:I and J:J)

Comment: If you want a single cell to sum all the individual rows then something like `=SUM(IF(DATEDIF(I:I,J:J,"D")>=45,0.5,0))` (entered as an array formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter) would do it, but it would be better to restrict to the used range (eg I2:I200) rather than use the whole columns.

Comment: So basically having it this way? =SUM(IF(DATEDIF('Jira Sheet'!$I2:$I1000,'Jira Sheet'!$J2:$J1000,"D")>=45,0.5,0))

Comment: yess it's correct @mildlylost . It's seems on like how many rows you required. It works.

Comment: It is not adding them for some reason.. odd it seems like this would be correct =SUM(IF(DATEDIF('Jira Sheet'!I2:I1000,'Jira Sheet'!J2:J1000,"d")<=45,0.5,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you for an exact formula for your question.

```
=SUM(IF(DATEDIF('Jira Sheet'!$I2,'Jira Sheet'!$J2,"D")>=45,0.5,0)
```

> The same have been answered by @Tim Williams.

Comment: Is that formula right?  The closing paren for the SUM function looks like it is missing..  Maybe the SUM isn't needed since I2 and J2 aren't ranges?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the same has been tried my self. It works as per his requirement.

Comment: Sure, but it is missing a paren and it is summing up only one item.